# Is there an Excel formula that, given the ending cell, returns the starting cell of a block of data?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The data in column A looks like this.

RowHeaderThatIsText
RowHeaderThatIsNumber
*empty*
*empty*
*empty*
*empty*
*empty*
14.00
-3.00
-4.00

The project goal is to to calculate summary statistics for the series of numbers and update the summary each month.
My goal is to allow a new number to be added to the series and have the summary update automatically.

Here's what I've done so far.

1. Define a range named **LastCell** with the formula
   `=INDEX($A:$A, MAX(($A:$A <> "") * (ROW($A:$A))))`
   *This returns the last non-empty cell in the column.  The data to summarize is always the last block of numbers.*
2. Define a named range called **HeaderOffset** with the formula
   `=3`
   *Used in the step 3.*
3. Define a range named **FirstCell** with the formula
   `=OFFSET(LastCell, HeaderOffset - COUNTA($A:$A), 0)`
   *This returns the first cell of the last block of numbers if, as is the case with the data I'll be summarizing, the cells between the first and last blocks are empty.*
4. Define a range named **DataBlock** with the formula
   `=FirstCell:LastCell`

So far so good.  This allows one to enter =SUM(DataBlock) into any cell and get the expected result of 7.00.  And, if I add another value, say 3.00, to the list the SUM result will update to 10.

The part I don't like is HeaderOffset. If another row is added to the header, HeaderOffset needs to be updated from =3 to =4.  What if I forget to update HeaderOffset?  This lead me to the problem I can't currently solve...

Is there an Excel formula that, given the ending cell, returns the starting cell of a block of data?  Basically I'm looking for a **FirstCell** formula that removes the need for HeaderOffset.

As a bonus I was trying to do this whole thing without using [volatile Excel functions](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm).  I failed by using OFFSET.  Solving this is great.  Solving it without volatile functions is ideal.

Comment: what's wrong about `=SUM($A:$A)` or DataBlock defined as `=$A:$A`? do you really need to use numbers in the header?

Comment: Yes.  One of the header columns is a number and it really needs to be that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is FirstCell always the first number? If so try this to define FirstCell

`=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER($A:$A),0))`

That's an "array formula" if entered on the worksheet but doesn't need any special treatment if used in the "refers to:" box to define a named range.

Note: if your final aim is the sum of the numbers then could you just use `=SUM(A:A)` [I assume that's oversimplifying the issue?]

**Revised given comment below:**

Try this for LastCell

`=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(9.99E+307,$A:$A))`

and this one for FirstCell

`=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(2,1/($A$1:LastCell=""))+1)`

assumes LastCell is numeric (although that can be changed if required)

Comment: Hi Barry.  Thanks for the answer.  No, FirstCell is not the first number because the header includes a number.  I've updated the sample data accordingly.  And yes, =SUM(A:A) is oversimplifying but I thought it got the point across for the question.  :-)

Comment: barry, that is a seriously clever way to feed INDEX a useful array.  Thanks!  I marked your answer as accepted but if you don't mind I have a couple of follow-up questions. 1) Is there a reason to use the LastCell formula from your answer vs the one from my question? 2) Is there a reason you used **Match(2,** instead of **Match(1,**?  
Thanks again.

Comment: OK, after a little testing, and thinking, it's pretty clear your version of LastCell is magnitudes faster.  Doing a math operation on every single cell in the column makes my version ridiculous in comparison.  Maybe you have similar reasons for **Match(2**?